# Um controle - várias propriedades

Tags: c#, uwp

Tenho um Combobox e ele tem como itemssource um struct com algumas propriedades, e eu tenho uma viewModel que tem algumas propriedades deste struct, eu quero saber se existe uma forma de fazer com que o combobox defina os parâmetros da viewmodel iguais a determinados parâmetros do item selecionado.

Claro, eu poderia criar mais uma propriedade da minha VM e ela ser do tipo daquele struct, então eu colocaria o selecteditem do combobox igual a esta nova propriedade, infelizmente neste cenário específico eu não posso fazer isso.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource estados}, Path=Siglas}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Emit.endereco.SiglaUF, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Header="Estado" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Emit.endereco.SiglaUF, Converter={StaticResource obterMunicipios}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ConjuntoMunicipio, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Nome"
                      Header="Município" />

    public Municipio ConjuntoMunicipio
    {
        get => Municipios.Get(Emit.endereco.SiglaUF).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Codigo == Emit.endereco.CodigoMunicipio);
        set
        {
            Emit.endereco.NomeMunicipio = value?.Nome;
            Emit.endereco.CodigoMunicipio = value?.Codigo ?? 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: posta o que voce ja tem de codigo que ai o pessoal consegue ajudar melhor

Comment: Não sei se isso vai ajudar muito.

Comment: pode acreditar! ;)

Comment: Estou acreditando e esperando kkk

Comment: @andrepaulo agora tem como saber o que é ConjuntoMunicipio.